# Can an opamp be used in a 75MHz narrow band pass filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, passive-networks

My exposure to EE is more than half a century old (sorry). I want to investigate the near-field pattern of a variety of antenna configurations at 75MHz. I have purchased an AD8307 broadband detector power meter. I intend to feed that from an array of simple dipoles (quarter wavelength = one meter). The receiving antenna will be an identical array. I am interested in inserting a narrow bandpass filter between the receiving antenna and the detector to minimize stray noise effects. An opamp active filter looked promising until I tried to find one that would be appropriate for 75MHz. The highest gain-bandwidth product that I have found for an opamp is 20MHz. I assume that means that an LC passive filter is what I need. Should this be the series version with the lowest inductor resistance that I can arrange?

Comment: There are plenty of Opamps that go beyond 200Mhz. You may have more luck searching for video opamps. These usually have higher gain-bandwidth product.

Comment: You can get GHz opamps, ada4817 for instance, but you shouldn't. Use an LC bandpass filter. Inductor resistance doesn't have to be 'lowest', just 'low enough' for the bandwidth you want. If it's merely noise filtering, then it doesn't need to be very selective, which means very high inductor Q is not required.

Comment: "My exposure to EE is more than half a century old" welcome to the old-timers club :)

Comment: Just roughly you would need an amplifier with bandwidth greater than your desired Q times the center frequency. So if you want a Q of 10 you'd need something approaching 1GHz, which is possible, but I would suggest a passive LC filter.

Answer (score 2):

A strictly passive approach might be investigated. Since the AD8307 has balanced inputs having differential impedance of 1100 ohms, a filter can serve two purposes: match the 72 ohm dipole impedance to 1100 ohms, and filter unwanted frequencies. The data sheet gives values for an unbalanced filter for various frequencies (*fig.35 High Frequency Input Matching Network*).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkrCBN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The matching network shown above is a quickie attempt that's roughly in the right ballpark for 75 MHz. Out-of-band attenuation may be insufficient to knock down strong signals in a noisy environment...the bandwidth of this device is very wide.

Comment: Thank you gentlepeople. I would not have known how to calculate the L and C values. The resonant frequency of the series 9pF and 390nH is about 85MHz. Is it only necessary that the L be sufficiently large that its reactance at 75MHz be large compared to 72 ohms? (2pi x 75MHz x 390nH = 184 ohms)? And that the C be large enough that its reactance at 75MHz  be smaller than 1100 ohms (1/(2pi x 75MHz x 9pF)) = 236 ohms)? PS, I assume that the inductor must be air core?

Comment: One further question, must the self-resonant frequency be far above 75 MHz? They appear not to be stocked, and to command a pretty penny.

Comment: AD8307 has internal capacitance. And added to that is external capacitance (stray). A dipole antenna cut by formula will likely be off resonance, adding or subtracting more reactance. So the matching network can only be "ballpark", and will need tweaking. An air-wound magnet-wire inductor can be tweaked to lower inductance by spreading turns. Having to tweak is to be expected in LC narrow-band filters.